# Playing two MediaPlayer objects in sync [Android]

Tags: android, synchronization, android-mediaplayer

I have two media files located locally - mp4 video and m4a audio, which have to be played in sync. I use MediaPlayer objects for this purpose, all start/pause methods are called simultaneously.

Sometimes I see the difference between audio and video right after players start, sometimes after tapping on pause/resume.

I added logs, and see that after pausing media players, their position differs (e.g. MediaPlayer with audio file: 1820ms, MediaPlayer with video file: 1760ms).

One more interesting thing is that seekTo operation with audio file works good, while with video it's really unpredictable.

Please suggest what is the reason of such a behavior and which solutions are available in order to fix that?

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: This is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100318/having-2-mediaplayer-objects-playing-in-sync-android . I think soundpool is just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this effect with the video timing depends on how the " key frames", which contain a full frame of information have been encoded. It's only possible to locate to one of these keyframes.
Video editing software gets over this by rolling the deltas from intervening i-frames to the exact seek position.